# WPF Dependency property not being set at initialization

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, dependency-properties

I'm trying to set width of UserControl at initialization time in ViewModel, but it receives only zero. When I resize the window, it receives correct width.

MainWindow.xaml extract:

```
<local:MapControl x:Name="MapControl" 
    DataContext="{Binding MapViewModel}"
    ActualControlWidth="{Binding ActualControlWidth, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

MapControl.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MapControl : UserControl
{
    public MapControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SizeChanged += OnControlSizeChanged;
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActualControlWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ActualControlWidth",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(MapControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(PropertyChangedCallback)); //here it does not have any influence if i put default(double) or not

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newVar = e.NewValue;
    }

    public double ActualControlWidth
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ActualControlWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ActualControlWidthProperty, value); } //here comes the value as 785
    }

    private void OnControlSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ActualControlWidth = ActualWidth;
    }
}
```

MapViewModel.cs:

```
public class MapViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private double _actualControlWidth;
    private Map _map;

    public MapViewModel()
    {
       ...
    }

    public Map Map
    {
        get => _map;
        set => Set(() => Map, ref _map, value);
    }

    public double ActualControlWidth
    {
        get => _actualControlWidth;
        set => _actualControlWidth = value; //this is where the value comes as 0
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

The full reproduction example is at my Github https://github.com/czechdude/dependencypropertyissue

Comment: It works fine for me. As a note, instead of attaching a SizeChanged event handler, you may also override the OnRenderSizeChanged method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update this line:

```
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(PropertyChangedCallback)); //here it does not have any influence if i put default(double) or not
```

To

```
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(defaultValue: -1.0D, 
     new PropertyChangedCallback(MethodToCall));

...

private static void MethodToCall(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
 // call second method to make instance of MapControl and call a custom method that sets your ActualControlWidth
}
```